# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error on .OwnsMany() when creating EF Core migration for multiple Aggregates

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-migrations

I'm building an app following the DDD principles and using Aggregates, Entities and Value objects. These are my two aggregate roots for which I wrote configurations which are then used for building EF Core migrations:

`Office.cs` which has a list of `DepartmentId`'s for referencing the other aggregate:

```cs
public class Office : AggregateRoot<OfficeId>
{
    private readonly List<DepartmentId> _departmentIds = new();

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; private set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<DepartmentId> DepartmentIds => _departmentIds.AsReadOnly();

    private Office(OfficeId officeId, string name, DateTime createdDateTime, DateTime updatedDateTime) :
        base(officeId)
    {
        Name = name;
        CreatedDateTime = createdDateTime;
        UpdatedDateTime = updatedDateTime;
    }

    public static Office Create(int officeId, string name)
    {
        return new Office(OfficeId.Create(officeId), name, DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow);
    }

    private Office(){}
}
```

`Department.cs` which has a list of `MunicipalityId`'s for referencing `Municipality` aggreate, which is not shown here.

```cs
public class Department : AggregateRoot<DepartmentId>
{
    private readonly List<MunicipalityId> _municipalityIds = new();

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public OfficeId OfficeId { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; private set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<MunicipalityId> MunicipalityIds => _municipalityIds.AsReadOnly();

    private Department(DepartmentId departmentId, string name, OfficeId officeId, DateTime createdDateTime, DateTime updatedDateTime) :
        base(departmentId)
    {
        Id = departmentId;
        Name = name;
        OfficeId = officeId;
        CreatedDateTime = createdDateTime;
        UpdatedDateTime = updatedDateTime;
    }

    public static Department Create(DepartmentId departmentId, string name, OfficeId officeId)
    {
        return new Department(departmentId, name, officeId,DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow);
    }

    private Department(){}
}
```

Now the entity builder configurations which are then used in the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` to create migrations.

`OfficeConfigurations`

```cs
public class OfficeConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Office>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Office> builder)
    {
        ConfigureOfficeTable(builder);
        ConfigureDepartmentIdTable(builder);
    }

    private void ConfigureOfficeTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Office> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Office), nameof(Office));
        
        builder.HasKey(o => o.Id);
        
        builder.Property(o => o.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value,
                value => OfficeId.Create(value));
    }

    private void ConfigureDepartmentIdTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Office> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsMany(o => o.DepartmentIds, departmentIdBuilder =>
        {
            departmentIdBuilder.ToTable(nameof(DepartmentId), nameof(Office));
            
            departmentIdBuilder.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(nameof(OfficeId));
            
            departmentIdBuilder.HasKey("Id"); // shadow id property
            
            departmentIdBuilder.Property(did => did.Value)
                .HasColumnName(nameof(DepartmentId))
                .ValueGeneratedNever();
        });
        
        builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Office.DepartmentIds))!
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

`DepartmentConfigurations`

```cs
public class DepartmentConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Department>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Department> builder)
    {
        ConfigureDepartmentTable(builder);
        ConfigureMunicipalityIdTable(builder);
    }

    private void ConfigureDepartmentTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Department> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Department), nameof(Department));

        builder.HasKey(d => d.Id);

        builder.Property(d => d.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value,
                value => DepartmentId.Create(value));

        builder.Property(d => d.OfficeId)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value,
                value => OfficeId.Create(value));
    }

    private void ConfigureMunicipalityIdTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Department> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsMany(d => d.MunicipalityIds, municipalityIdBuilder =>
        {
            municipalityIdBuilder.ToTable(nameof(MunicipalityId), nameof(Department));
        
            municipalityIdBuilder.WithOwner().HasForeignKey(nameof(DepartmentId));
        
            municipalityIdBuilder.HasKey("Id"); // shadow id property
        
            municipalityIdBuilder.Property(mid => mid.Value)
                .HasColumnName(nameof(MunicipalityId))
                .ValueGeneratedNever();
        });

        builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Department.MunicipalityIds))!
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

When I try to add a migration using `dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration` using just one of these configuration (either `OfficeConfigurations` or `DepartmentConfigurations`) the migration is successfully created. The problem is when I try to create a migration using both configurations, or the rest of other configurations I didn't show here I get a strange `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. When running the two shown configurations the stack trace is the following:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionBatchExtensions.Run(IConventionBatch batch, InternalForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalForeignKeyBuilder.ReuniquifyImplicitProperties(Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ForeignKeyPropertyDiscoveryConvention.DiscoverProperties(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder, IConventionContext c
ontext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ForeignKeyPropertyDiscoveryConvention.ProcessForeignKeyRequirednessChanged(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder, IC
onventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnForeignKeyRequirednessChanged(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshi
pBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnForeignKeyRequirednessChangedNode.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.DelayedConventionScope.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run(IConventionForeignKey foreignKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.OwnsManyBuilder[TRelatedEntity](TypeIdentity ownedType, MemberIdentity navigation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.OwnsMany[TRelatedEntity](Expression`1 navigationExpression, Action`1 buildAction)
   at Ratsatak.Infrastructure.Persistence.Configurations.DepartmentConfigurations.ConfigureMunicipalityIdTable(EntityTypeBuilder`1 builder) in D:\DevCollections\Ratsatak\Ratsatak.Infra
structure\Persistence\Configurations\DepartmentConfigurations.cs:line 39
   at Ratsatak.Infrastructure.Persistence.Configurations.DepartmentConfigurations.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder`1 builder) in D:\DevCollections\Ratsatak\Ratsatak.Infrastructure\Persisten
ce\Configurations\DepartmentConfigurations.cs:line 15
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration[TEntity](IEntityTypeConfiguration`1 configuration)
   at Ratsatak.Infrastructure.Persistence.RatsatakDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in D:\DevCollections\Ratsatak\Ratsatak.Infrastructure\Persistence\RatsatakDbConte
xt.cs:line 33
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope ser
viceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope ser
viceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope ser
viceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope ser
viceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope ser
viceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope ser
viceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Which points out to the line `builder.OwnsMany(d => d.MunicipalityIds, municipalityIdBuilder => {...});` in `DepartmentConfigurations`.

I'm clueless why when I run just one configuration, the migration succedes but the opposite is true when two configurations are involved, and the error appears to happen when defining a `.OwnsMany()` relationship which is not tied to the preceeding aggregate.

Am I missing something here?